# using while loop in c#,count between two num's printing only num's that divisible by the third num

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am working on while loops.I am currently working on a problem that ask to get three numbers from the user named a,b and c. I try to display all numbers between a and b,which divide by c.I played around with the ideas of using an "if" , but have had no luck.

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("enter 3 num");
        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        int num3 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (num1 > num2) {
            while (num2 % num3 == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine (num2);
                num2++;
            }
        } else {
            while (num1 % num3 == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine (num1);
                num1++;
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: Show what did you tried and where you haven't luck. Otherwise your question seems like "Do my homework for me"

Comment: public static void Main (string[] args)
  {
   Console.WriteLine ("enter 3 num");
   int num1 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
   int num2 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
   int num3 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
   if (num1 > num2) {
    while (num2 % num3 == 0) {
     Console.WriteLine (num2);
     num2++;
    }
   } else {
    while (num1 % num3 == 0) {
     Console.WriteLine (num1);
     num1++;
    }
   }

  }

Comment: Let's say you enter `5`, `20` and `2`. The first time your code hits the condition for the while loop, it says `is 5 exactly divisible by 2?`, the answer is no, so the program ends. Or, you enter num3 as 1 and end up in an infinite loop. Think about what the exit condition should be for your while loop - a condition that is false when you no longer want the loop to be entered.

Comment: Your while statement continues to run if all the numbers between a and b are divisible by c. You want to move num1 % num3 to an if inside the while statement and change the while to while(num1 < num2) and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Your approach (and the other answers so far) are testing every number between `a` and `b` which is perfectly fine.

What I've tried below is to find the first factor >= to `a` with a simple calculation then keep adding `c` to this number until we go over our upper bound, `b`.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    // Note: This crashes if non numeric characters are entered!
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter 3 numbers:");
    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int divisor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // Find the lowest and highest in case they are entered in the wrong order
    int lowerNum = Math.Min(num1, num2); 
    int upperNum = Math.Max(num1, num2); 

    // Find the first factor over the lower bound
    // E.g. for a = 10, b = 20, c = 3, we have remainder = 1
    //      = 10 + (3 - 1)
    //      = 12
    int remainder = lowerNum % divisor;
    int factor = (remainder == 0)
      ? lowerNum 
      : lowerNum + (divisor - remainder);

    // Calculate all other factors up to the upper bound by simple addition
    while(factor <= upperNum){
      Console.WriteLine(factor);

      factor += divisor;
    }

}
```

Advantages of this approach:

- Less tests in the for loop
- Using addition (+) rather than modulo (%)

[.NET Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s3vcJ9)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach...

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetDividableNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int start = Math.Min(a, b);
    int quantity = Math.Abs(a - b);
    return Enumerable.Range(start, quantity).Where(num => num % c == 0);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (int i in GetDividableNumbers(0, 5, 2))
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

If you want to use only `while` then use `Enumerator`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = GetDividableNumbers(10, -3, 3);
    IEnumerator<int> enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext() == true)
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter 3 num");
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int n = num1;
while (n <= num2)
{
    if (n % num3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
    n++;
}
```

Comment: am i have to assigning the small number as n? would it work if i do it without an assigning?

Comment: @naorohayon - Well, you could use `num1` instead of introducing `n`, but it is a better coding practice to use `n` as separates the working variables from the input variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've already got `num1`, `num2` and `num3` from the user:

```
int n1 = Math.Min(num1, num2); //num1 is the small number
int n2 = Math.Max(num1, num2); //num2 is the large number

while(n1 <= n2) {
    if (n1 % num3 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(n);
     n1++
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, if you originally entered 2 as `num1` and 1 for `num2`, after your first two statements both `num1` and `num2` are then equal to 1. Also `n` should be `i`. Also, a `while` loop was requested.

Comment: Yes thank you, the n was supposed to be i. That was a typing error.
And no, look at the first two statements again. One of them is max and the other is min. Also, a for loop could be easily converted to a while loop. Just initialize the counter before the loop and increment it inside. Not rocket science

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. Given `num1 = 2` and `num2 = 1`, `Math.Min(num1 (1), num2 (2))` sets `num1` to 1. The next statement is then `num2 = Math.Max(num1 (1), num2 (1))`, where both `num1` and `num2` are now both `1`, leaving `num2` at 1. It's wrong.

Comment: @naor ohayon I edited it to a while loop. This should work

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is to print all the divisors of a specific number given that you have 2 numbers and you want to take the minimum, so you can do the following.

and in your main function you can do the following

```
Console.WriteLine("enter 3 num");
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int a = Math.Min(num1,num2);
int b = Math.Max(num1,num2);
int num = a;
while(num <= b)
{
   if(num%num3 ==0)
      Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}/{2}={3}", num, num,num3, num/num3);
   num++;
}
```

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A9Ay5y)

result for num1 = 45 and num2 = 30 and num3 = 3

```
enter 3 num
45
30
3
30, 30/3=10
33, 33/3=11
36, 36/3=12
39, 39/3=13
42, 42/3=14
45, 45/3=15
```

Comment: I think the question is asking for all divisors between the range a to b, so if a=80, b= 90 and c = 5 you would print 80, 85, 90.